# Exported function forwarded to itself?

Tags: c++, windows, portable-executable

I ran into an extremely weird issue today when messing around with the parsing the Windows Portable Executable file structure today. Specifically in the Export table.

I found myself getting a Stack Overflow (so this seemed like the most appropriate QA board) when trying to resolve the function address of an Exported function in a DLL.

I've written my own version of `GetProcAddress` which does the parsing manually rather than calling the existing `GetProcAddress` method. Please don't just tell me to use the existing `GetProcAddress` method, it's not suitable for my current situation and I want to learn something from this.

For most of the situations I encounter, my version has worked admirably and hasn't hit any issues. However the function was tested against a DLL named `API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll` (as part of a recursive parse of `Kernel32.dll`) and this is when the StackOverflow occurred.

I've narrowed it down to the following function exported from `API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll`:

```
CreateRemoteThreadEx
```

Now, this exported function is actually a forwarded export. Usually this is no worries; I've written my function so that it should handle forwarded exports. However this function is forwarded to

`api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.CreateRemoteThreadEx`

Anyone seeing the problem here? Stepping through the code, my `GetProcAddress` function then calls `LoadLibrary` on `api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0` and then attempts to recursively lookup `CreateRemoteThreadEx`. On the very next iteration, however, the `CreateRemoteThreadEx` function is again forwarded... to

`api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.CreateRemoteThreadEx`

And so begins the StackOverflow. After a bit more investigation I found that the result of calling

```
LoadLibraryA("api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0");
```

Returns the same result as

```
LoadLibraryA("kernel32.dll");
```

I'm stumped.

Here's my current code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define MKPTR(p1,p2) ((DWORD_PTR)(p1) + (DWORD_PTR)(p2))

INT LookupExport(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pDosHd, DWORD* pNames, DWORD nNames, LPCSTR lpProcName)
{
    // Do a binary search on the name pointer table
    INT start = 0, 
        index = -1,
        middle = -1, 
        end = nNames - 1,
        cmp = 0;

    CHAR *pName;

    while (start <= end && index == -1)
    {
        middle = (start + end) >> 1;
        pName = (CHAR*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pNames[middle]);

        if ((cmp = strcmp(pName, lpProcName)) == 0)
            index = middle; // found
        else if (cmp < 0)
            start = middle + 1;
        else
            end = middle;
    }

    return index;
}

FARPROC InternalGetProcAddress(HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR lpProcName)
{
    BOOL ordinalSearch = HIWORD(lpProcName) == 0;
    WORD ordinal = 0;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *pDosHd = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)hModule;

    if (pDosHd->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *pNtHd = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pDosHd->e_lfanew);
    if (pNtHd->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;

    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY directory = pNtHd->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT];
    if (directory.Size == 0 || directory.VirtualAddress == 0)
        return NULL;

    IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *pExports = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)MKPTR(pDosHd, directory.VirtualAddress);
    if (!ordinalSearch)
    {
        INT index = LookupExport(pDosHd, (DWORD*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pExports->AddressOfNames), pExports->NumberOfNames, lpProcName);
        if (index == -1)
            return NULL;
        ordinal = ((WORD*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pExports->AddressOfNameOrdinals))[index];
    }
    else
    {
        ordinal = LOWORD(lpProcName);
    }

    INT delta = pExports->Base - 1;
    DWORD dwAddress = ((DWORD*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pExports->AddressOfFunctions))[ordinal - delta];
    // Check whether forwarded:
    if (dwAddress >= directory.VirtualAddress && dwAddress < (directory.VirtualAddress + directory.Size))
    {
        CHAR pForward[256];
        strcpy(pForward, (CHAR*)MKPTR(pDosHd, dwAddress));
        CHAR *pFunction = strchr(pForward, '.');
        if (pFunction == NULL)
            return NULL;

        // break into seperate parts and recurse
        *pFunction++ = 0;
        return InternalGetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA(pForward), pFunction);
    }

    return (FARPROC)MKPTR(hModule, dwAddress);
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm one of the few people I know who have played with and manipulated PE/COFF headers, so I'll try to help.  But it's been several years, so bear with me.  The situation seems like a linker bug.  Isn't it sufficient to simply check that the forward isn't to the same file?   What does dumpbin do with that symbol?  Does it resolve it?

Comment: Not sure how checking if it forwards to the same DLL would help, as it still doesn't resolve into a usable address :/

Comment: I understand, which is why I suggested checking if dumpbin can resolve it.  It would be nice to know if there is a solution before we try to find it.

Comment: The "real" `GetProcAddress` has no dramas looking up the function. Unfortunately DUMPBIN is being stupid on my current computer so I can't check the output. DependencyWalker and PE Explorer are completely unhelpful though as they don't seem to follow forwarded exports.

Comment: That GetProcAddress resolves the function is strong evidence that there is a solution.  This leads me to wonder if the cyclic reference isn't a convention for resolving it to a specific place, perhaps not in the file.  In case you haven't guessed, I don't really have an answer.  Use me as a sounding board. :-)

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. I took a look at some of the ReactOS and as far as I can tell they do it the same way as I'm going about it (albeit in a slightly more roundabout fashion).

Comment: Internal API architecture is separated from implementation 
Virtual DLLs can be combined at build time for efficiency 
`MinWin` APIs first ones factored into virtual DLLs: `API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll` The mapping of virtual to logical is stored in a schema that’s embedded in `Apisetschema.dll` 
Kernel reads schema during boot and maps it into every process for quick lookup Loader refers to schema for DLL loads that are pathless to find mapping Virtual DLLs images present on system for application compatibility with tools like Dependency Walker Not used by loader

Comment: [Virtual DLL->ApiSetSchema.dll->Logical DLL](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:9VvBqvUOQY8J:download.microsoft.com/download/6/7/3/673B71D0-6D4F-4591-9940-D33DF9135487/WSV402_Windows_7_and_Server_changes_Human.pptx+&hl=ru&gl=ru&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESj0CLRwIGjM-ntKZrKalE1V0LUE6xLg09fdCU3v8p_lHO7o-rkr6P5Ax_ilTrWCJRRtXEHgwPvz7zvc5twnbMtYUm3AkMoY7-3X8b4nqRs3hPjkpjvoB_M5NC73H2cMHNJQNcnb&sig=AHIEtbQHqQKWjjCtZRggZw_6SZSmwEeQ8A)

Comment: Ah shit, figures Microsoft would pull something like this.

Comment: @JasonLarke: Now that you've got it figured out, don't forget to post an answer to your own question.  It's a valid thing to do, and it's useful information.

Comment: I haven't figured it out just yet, but I'm getting closer. I will be sure to post my full working copy once it's finished. Thanks to sergmat though, definitely on the right track now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay after following @sergmat's advice I took a look at the API Set documentation (found [here](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/index.htm) for anyone interested). I've now modified my GetProcAddress code to do a naive lookup of the Api Set table.

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define MKPTR(p1,p2) ((DWORD_PTR)(p1) + (DWORD_PTR)(p2))

typedef struct _stripped_peb32 {
    BYTE    unused1[0x038];
    PVOID   ApiSet;
    BYTE    unused2[0x1AC];
} PEB32;

typedef struct _stripped_peb64 {
    BYTE    unused1[0x068];
    PVOID   ApiSet;
    BYTE    unused2[0x23C];
} PEB64;

typedef struct _PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION {
    PVOID       Reserved1;
    LPVOID      PebBaseAddress;
    PVOID       Reserved2[2];
    ULONG_PTR   UniqueProcessId;
    PVOID       Reserved3;
} PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _api_set_host {
    DWORD           ImportModuleName;
    WORD            ImportModuleNameLength;
    DWORD           HostModuleName;
    WORD            HostModuleNameLength;
} API_SET_HOST;

typedef struct _api_set_host_descriptor {
    DWORD           NumberOfHosts;
    API_SET_HOST    Hosts[1];
} API_SET_HOST_DESCRIPTOR;

typedef struct _api_set_entry {
    DWORD           Name;
    WORD            NameLength;
    DWORD           HostDescriptor;
} API_SET_ENTRY;

typedef struct _api_set_header {
    DWORD           unknown1;
    DWORD           NumberOfEntries;
    API_SET_ENTRY   Entries[1];
} API_SET_HEADER;

typedef NTSTATUS (__stdcall *fnNtQueryInformationProcess)(HANDLE ProcessHandle, DWORD ProcessInformationClass, PVOID ProcessInformation, ULONG ProcessInformationLength, PULONG ReturnLength);

API_SET_HEADER *GetApiSetHeader()
{
    fnNtQueryInformationProcess NtQueryInformationProcess = (fnNtQueryInformationProcess)GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryW(L"ntdll.dll"), "NtQueryInformationProcess");
    if (!NtQueryInformationProcess)
        return NULL;

    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION info;
    if (NtQueryInformationProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), 0, &info, sizeof(info), NULL) != S_OK)
        return NULL;

#if defined(_WIN32)
    return (API_SET_HEADER*)(((PEB32*)info.PebBaseAddress)->ApiSet);
#elif defined(_WIN64)
    return (API_SET_HEADER*)(((PEB64*)info.PebBaseAddress)->ApiSet);
#else
    return NULL; // unsupported architecture
#endif
}

HMODULE ResolveImportMap(LPCSTR lpModuleName)
{
    API_SET_HEADER *pHeader = GetApiSetHeader();
    if (pHeader == NULL)
        return NULL;
    API_SET_ENTRY *pEntry = pHeader->Entries;
    API_SET_HOST_DESCRIPTOR* pDescriptor;
    wchar_t module[128];

    // First, normalize the LPCSTR, the API Set table doesn't have the API- prefix
    if (strnicmp("api-", lpModuleName, 4) == 0)
        lpModuleName += 4;

    // Next convert the LPCSTR to a unicode string for comparison and remove the extension (if found)
    mbstowcs(module, lpModuleName, sizeof(module) / sizeof(wchar_t));
    wchar_t *dot = wcsrchr(module, L'.');
    if (dot) *dot = L'\0';

    // Begin the lookup:
    // todo: implement a case-insensitive binary search, not much to be gained for the effort IMO as there's
    //          only 35 entries in the current version of Windows 7, but the option is there for performance nuts.
    for(unsigned long i = 0; i < pHeader->NumberOfEntries; ++i, ++pEntry)
    {
        // Check the top-level host map
        if (wcsnicmp(module, (const wchar_t*)MKPTR(pHeader, pEntry->Name), pEntry->NameLength) == 0)
        {
            pDescriptor = (API_SET_HOST_DESCRIPTOR*)MKPTR(pHeader, pEntry->HostDescriptor);
            // iterate backwards through the hosts to find the most important one (I think this is naive)
            for(unsigned long j = pDescriptor->NumberOfHosts; j > 0; --j)
            {
                if (pDescriptor->Hosts[j - 1].HostModuleNameLength)
                {
                    memcpy(module, (const void*)MKPTR(pHeader, pDescriptor->Hosts[j - 1].HostModuleName), pDescriptor->Hosts[j - 1].HostModuleNameLength);
                    module[pDescriptor->Hosts[j - 1].HostModuleNameLength / sizeof(wchar_t)] = L'\0';
                    return GetModuleHandleW(module); // All the modules should already be loaded, so use GetModuleHandle rather than LoadLibrary
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

INT LookupExport(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* pDosHd, DWORD* pNames, DWORD nNames, LPCSTR lpProcName)
{
    // Do a binary search on the name pointer table
    INT start = 0, 
        index = -1,
        middle = -1, 
        end = nNames - 1,
        cmp = 0;

    CHAR *pName;

    while (start <= end && index == -1)
    {
        middle = (start + end) >> 1;
        pName = (CHAR*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pNames[middle]);

        if ((cmp = strcmp(pName, lpProcName)) == 0)
            index = middle; 
        else if (cmp < 0)
            start = middle + 1;
        else
            end = middle;
    }

    return index;
}

FARPROC InternalGetProcAddress(HMODULE hModule, LPCSTR lpProcName)
{
    if (hModule == NULL)
        return NULL;

    BOOL ordinalSearch = HIWORD(lpProcName) == 0;
    WORD ordinal = 0;
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *pDosHd = (IMAGE_DOS_HEADER*)hModule;

    if (pDosHd->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *pNtHd = (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pDosHd->e_lfanew);
    if (pNtHd->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
        return NULL;

    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY directory = pNtHd->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT];
    if (directory.Size == 0 || directory.VirtualAddress == 0)
        return NULL;

    IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY *pExports = (IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY*)MKPTR(pDosHd, directory.VirtualAddress);
    if (!ordinalSearch)
    {
        INT index = LookupExport(pDosHd, (DWORD*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pExports->AddressOfNames), pExports->NumberOfNames, lpProcName);
        if (index == -1)
            return NULL;
        ordinal = ((WORD*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pExports->AddressOfNameOrdinals))[index];
    }
    else
    {
        ordinal = LOWORD(lpProcName);
    }

    INT ordbase = pExports->Base - 1;
    DWORD dwAddress = ((DWORD*)MKPTR(pDosHd, pExports->AddressOfFunctions))[ordinal - ordbase];
    // Check whether forwarded:
    if (dwAddress >= directory.VirtualAddress && dwAddress < (directory.VirtualAddress + directory.Size))
    {
        CHAR pForward[256];
        strcpy(pForward, (CHAR*)MKPTR(pDosHd, dwAddress));
        CHAR *pFunction = strchr(pForward, '.');
        if (pFunction == NULL)
            return NULL;

        // break into seperate parts and recurse
        *pFunction++ = 0;
        // check if ordinal-forwarded
        if (*pFunction == '#')
            pFunction = (PSTR)(unsigned short)(atoi(++pFunction));

        HMODULE hDestination = LoadLibraryA(pForward);

        // detect an infinite loop, the forward declaration requests the same module handle with 
        // the same function lookup, this could be an Api Set (Windows7+)
        if (hDestination == hModule && (ordinalSearch ? LOWORD(pFunction) == LOWORD(lpProcName) : strcmp(pFunction, lpProcName) == 0))
            hDestination = ResolveImportMap(pForward); // ResolveImportMap will return NULL if not an API Set and so avoid infinite recursion

        return InternalGetProcAddress(hDestination, pFunction);
    }

    return (FARPROC)MKPTR(hModule, dwAddress);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be outdated, still useful though